# How to write a P6 ppm

Tags: java, binary, ascii, ppm

I understand how to read and write a P3 ppm file, and that it is in ASCII. I know that in P6 ppm it is written in binary, but I have no idea how to write one of my own. Of course I know how to write in binary, but I've seen P6 ppm files with weird characters like this: `ÿ`. I don't understand what that has to do with binary. Can someone explain?

Comment: Binary files are not written in characters.  When you are seeing your `ÿ`, you are seeing some binary data in the file being misinterpreted as a character by whatever software you're using to display the file.  (`cat`?  `more`?)  What exactly is your understanding of how to write a file in binary?

Comment: I guess it's something like this:
P6
1 2
255 # Not sure what to put here
11111111
10101010

Comment: That's not what it really means to write a binary file.  You are still using characters for `1` and `0`.  You need to write actual bytes corresponding to those values into the file.

Comment: Is it possible to put here an example so I can examine it and do my owns in the future?

Comment: That's really too much to answer in a forum like this.  I would suggest you read this part of the Java Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: Well, anyway, here's a hint.  For something like `11111111`. you end up with something like `byte x = 0xff`.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I'll also read the link you put.